# Resizing/shrinking .JPG files without losing quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, resize, image-quality, jpg

Im using Gimp to resize images. When using a high res image normally 4500 x 2994 i usually need to shrink this image to 325 x 130 pixels.

As you can imagine i loose the shiny, glossy and high res quality oof the image. Ive tried to save the image as .bmp and then resize it, this has made a slight difference but not a considerable change.

What else can i do to ensure i retain the hi-res quality of the image?

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1):

Downsizing ultimately means that you loose information. You can only try to
achieve a "good" result.

Here are three possible options that come to my mind:

- sharpen the image before downsizing
- cut out the most important part of the image
- downsize 50% several times instead of resizing once

Comment: +1 for *cut out the most important part* I think this will help on this strange format.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the *from* and *to* formats are incommensurable, that means you add a lot of extra-noise to the JPG noise:

- 2994 = 2 * 3 * 499
- 4500 = 2<sup>2</sup> * 3<sup>2</sup> * 5<sup>3</sup>

You may have better results when scaling by common factors, in this case 6:

- 4500/6 = 750
- 2994/6 = 499

I'd try a tool that is specialized for this kind of work, maybe [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) will help you. This tool is aware of the JPG specificity and has options to control the output. If I'm right, Wikipedia uses it under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to find your best conversion comes when the main size reduction is by an integer factor.  So, first choose a large intermediate size; for a 325 x 130 target, you might choose 12x this, or 3900 x 1560.

Now transform your source image into this size (3900 x 1560) by cropping and/or scaling. Depending on your needs, choose cropping over scaling, and when scaling prefer an integer-based factor (like 1/2 = 50.0%, preferably, or 21/40 = 52.5%) over an oddball factor (like 1560/2994 = 52.1%).  You can usually manage with the "smoother" factor by cropping (or padding) before or after, e.g. after scaling a 2994-wide image by 21/40 to a 1572px-wide image, you could crop 12px off to get the 1560-wide image.

Finally scale the resulting intermediate 3900 x 1560 image into the target size (325 x 130).

Answer (score 0):

When resizing using Gimp, there's that 'link' icon that you click to retain the aspect ratio of the image when you drag from a corner (not an edge). That's what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use a better software for that much shrinking. I am not saying GIMP is bad, it is a great software, but you might preserve the quality of the photo with a tool like this: http://www.paintshoppro.com/en/pages/jpg-file/