# resize image from original to different smaller sizes

Tags: resize, image-quality, jpg

Assume that I want to resize a large image (i0) into different smaller images (i1, i2, i3... where i0 > i1 > i2 > i3 ...) and keep the original ratio when doing the resize. I wonder which of the following approach will generate better result -

1. i0 -> i1 -> i2 -> i3
2. i0 -> i1, i0 -> i2, i0 -> i3

Any inputs are welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: #2 will almost *always* provide better results.. but **a lot** depends upon what **format** you are saving to, what **application** you are using, and what the nature of the **original image** is.

Comment: forgot to mention that the image is in JPG format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jpg.. there's **no question** that #2 is the **only** acceptable method. Jpg is a **lossy format**. Every save throws away data. Resaving a jpg as a jpg **always** results in a lower quality image. For this reason you should **always** return to the original image if you need to resave. Having an original format such as tiff, png24/32, or psd would be better. But at times jpg may be all you have.

Related: [Resizing/shrinking .JPG files without losing quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/resizing-shrinking-jpg-files-without-losing-quality?rq=1)

Comment: Very helpful info! Also, I am using gimp2 to do the size and I do have the PNG format of the original image as well, should I do the resize using PNG instead (and then export as jpg later on)? If go with PNG, would the 2) still be better than 1)?

Comment: #2 is almost always better. I'd use the PNG, resize, then save as JPG.